# simple webkit Speech Synthesis test not working

Tags: google-chrome, webkit, undefined, text-to-speech

I'm playing around with the webkit speech synthesis API, trying to get it to speak text from an input box on the click of a button with the following code:

```js
if ("speechSynthesis" in window) {
               console.log("browser supports speech synthesis.");
            } else {
               console.log("browser does NOT support speech sythesis")
            }

            var speechMsgInput = $("#speech-input").value;

            function speak(text){
                var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
                msg.text = text;
                window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
            }

            $("#speakbtn").onclick = speak(speechMsgInput);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>

       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>SujiQ Dev.0</title>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 
   </head>
   
<body>
        <input type="text" id="speech-input" value="42" x-webkit-speech>
        <button id="speakbtn">Speak</button>

 </body>
 
</html>
```

Testing it on Chrome 43 and the console log reports that the webkit is supported. On loading the html, a female voice reads aloud "undefined". I tried giving the text box an initial value to see if that changes anything but no, still "undefined". Anyone familiar with how to get the speech synthesis webkit to read text input?

EDIT:
A console test shows that the value of the `<input>` tag (id #speech-input) is "undefined". But there is a value explicitly assigned to it - what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the file needed to be tested on a hosted site (as opposed to remotely drag-and-drop-into-the-browser style) so the API could access the internet. This fixed the `SpeechSynthesisUtterance()` object's `text` attribute from being "undefined"

Testing on a hosted site revealed strange output: The female voice read aloud "undefined", "does this work?", "does this work?", "does this work?", "it works after all", "it works after all", "it works after all" in succession - in other words the sample utterances I had forcibly assigned during testing one by one remotely... very odd that that was somehow cached...

Comment: not to mention that you need to use the `val()` method with jQuery to call for value, as opposed to `.value`...